# Sklearn won't properly import plot_confusion_matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am currently trying to follow [this scikit-learn example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html) to plot a confusion matrix for a classifier I have. However, I get an import error whenever I try and import with this line from my terminal:

```
 >>> from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_confusion_matrix' from 'sklearn.metrics' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py)
```

The main goal is to get this to work on a jupyter notebook (currently being run on Google Colab). The same import line gets this error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_confusion_matrix'`

Note that I have re-updated my sklearn, scipy, and numpy on my terminal and gotten the same error. [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html?highlight=plot_confusion_matrix) is the documentation for plot_confusion_matrix.

Comment: There is no `plot_confusion_matrix` in sklearn. You need to use `confusion_matrix` and write a function to plot the confusion matrix.

Comment: @ErnestSKirubakaran there is this package, the author also posted a link to it

Comment: The plot_confusion_matrix is in the newest version (0.22) of scikit. Most probably your installed version is not that. Either update your scikit installation or for older versions, check [the tutorial here](https://scikit-learn.org/0.21/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py)

Comment: @VivekKumar, hi, thanks! I was updating my sklearn, not my scikit-learn

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer: I was updating my sklearn instead of scikit-learn. This module is only available starting at 0.22, and I was running 0.21.2. Thanks @VivekKumar!